# Symfony2 DateRange custom type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to create a simple custom Symfony2 dateRange formType with a slight twist.

The idea is that the user can choose a string representation of the date eg "today", "this month" or "custom" start / end dates.

When the form is submitted if a user chooses a period eg: "today" the start and end submitted form data are ignored and the start and end are calculated based on the period.

When submitting the form with "custom" period:

```
When I fill in the form  
   And submit "period" with "custom"  
   And submit "start" with "2014-01-01"  
   And submit "end" with "2014-01-01"  
Then the form should display:  
    "custom" in the period select box  
    And "2014-01-01" in start  
    And "2014-01-01" in end
```

When submitting the form with "tomorrow" period (assuming the date is 2014-01-01):

```
When I fill in the form  
   And submit "period" with "tomorrow"  
Then the form should display:  
    "tomorrow" in the period select box  
    And "2014-01-02" in start  
    And "2014-01-02" in end
```

The view / norm data is an array consisting of a period (int), start, end.

```
$viewData = array(
    'period' => 0,
    'start' =>  new \DateTime()
    'end' =>  new \DateTime()
);
```

The model data is a DateRange value object.

```
<?php

namespace Nsm\Bundle\ApiBundle\Form\Model;

use DateTime;

class DateRange
{
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    protected $start;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    protected $end;

    /**
     * @param DateTime $start
     * @param DateTime $end
     */
    public function __construct(DateTime $start = null, DateTime $end = null)
    {
        $this->start = $start;
        $this->end   = $end;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTime $start
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStart(DateTime $start = null)
    {
        $this->start = $start;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getStart()
    {
        return $this->start;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTime $end
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setEnd(DateTime $end = null)
    {
        $this->end = $end;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getEnd()
    {
        return $this->end;
    }
}
```

The form type looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Nsm\Bundle\ApiBundle\Form\Type;

use Nsm\Bundle\ApiBundle\Form\DataTransformer\DateRangeToArrayTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;

class DateRangeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'period',
                'choice',
                array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'custom',
                        'today',
                        'tomorrow',
                    )
                )
            )
            ->add('start', 'date')
            ->add('end', 'date');

        $transformer = new DateRangeToArrayTransformer();
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                // Don't modify DateRange classes by reference, we treat
                // them like immutable value objects
                'by_reference'   => false,
                'error_bubbling' => false,
                // If initialized with a DateRange object, FormType initializes
                // this option to "DateRange". Since the internal, normalized
                // representation is not DateRange, but an array, we need to unset
                // this option.
                'data_class'        => null,
                'required'          => false
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'date_range';
    }
}
```

And finally the transformer looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Nsm\Bundle\ApiBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Nsm\Bundle\ApiBundle\Form\Model\DateRange;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class DateRangeToArrayTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * Model to Norm
     *
     * @param mixed $dateRange
     *
     * @return array|mixed|string
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException
     */
    public function transform($dateRange)
    {
        if (null === $dateRange) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!$dateRange instanceof DateRange) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($dateRange, 'DateRange');
        }

        return array(
            'period' => 0,
            'start' => $dateRange->getStart(),
            'end' => $dateRange->getEnd()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Norm to Model
     *
     * @param $value
     *
     * @return DateRange|null
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        if (null === $value) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!is_array($value)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, 'array');
        }

        // Check here if period is custom and calculate dates
        return new DateRange($value['start'], $value['end']);
    }
}
```

I've decided to store the normalised data as an array so I can keep the 'period' value.

The code above transforms the form data as expected but I still ave an issue of manipulating the start and end values based on the period value.

My first attempt was to change the value of start / end in the reverseTransform method of the transformer. However this would [break the bijective principal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAX13g5orwo&feature=youtu.be&t=16m).

Next attempt was to use events.

Using `FormEvents:PRE_SUBMIT` introduced a few more complications namely the date form type can be submitted as a raw single text or array.

Using `FormEvents:SUBMIT` allows me to manipulate the form data successfully. `$form->getData()` returns the correct \DateRange object. However the start, end child forms are not updated (their view data is already set).

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    // ... manipulate $data here based on period ...
    $event->setData($data);
});
```

So my question:

- Is there anyway to manipulate a parent form and affect the view / norm / model data of child forms?
- Is using events the correct way to manipulate the parent data?
- Should I be assigning events to the child start / end forms rather than the parent form?

Cheers Leevi

---

**Update**

Tweaking the data transformer to check the `period` in reverseTransform to check the period and return a new `DateRange` kinda works.

Pros:

- `$form->getData();` returns the correct `DateRange` object

Cons:

- `$form->get('end');` returns the child form but it's data does not reflect the modified data set in reverseTransform.
- start and end form fields in the view do not reflect not reflect the modified data set in reverseTransform
- [breaks the bijective principal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAX13g5orwo&feature=youtu.be&t=16m).

All of the cons relate to the fact that the changes in reverseTransform are not pushed down into the child forms as they are processed first.

```
<?php

namespace Nsm\Bundle\ApiBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Nsm\Bundle\ApiBundle\Form\Model\DateRange;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class DateRangeToArrayTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * Model to Norm
     *
     * @param mixed $dateRange
     *
     * @return array|mixed|string
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException
     */
    public function transform($dateRange)
    {
        if (null === $dateRange) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!$dateRange instanceof DateRange) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($dateRange, 'DateRange');
        }

        return array(
            'period' => 0,
            'start' => $dateRange->getStart(),
            'end' => $dateRange->getEnd()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Norm to Model
     *
     * @param $value
     *
     * @return DateRange|null
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        if (null === $value) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!is_array($value)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, 'array');
        }

        switch($value['period']) {
            // Custom
            case 0:
                $start = $value['start'];
                $end = $value['end'];
                break;
            // Today
            case 1:
                $start = new \DateTime('today');
                $end = new \DateTime('today');
                break;
            // Tomorrow
            case 2:
                $start = new \DateTime('tomorrow');
                $end = new \DateTime('tomorrow');
                break;
            // This week
            case 3:
                $start = new \DateTime('this week');
                $end = new \DateTime('this week');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // Check here if period is custom and calculate dates
        return new DateRange($start, $end);
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely give up the transformer and use custom getter/setters methods instead with validation to ensure the stability of your data.

Maybe I'm missing something that forces you to use transformers though...

Comment: I'm using transformers to retain the "period" in the normData.

Comment: Won't you have the period if using data_class? You don't need that data transformer over there. I think processing the `period` field can be done using a subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be assigning events to the child start / end forms rather than the parent form?

This sounds like a good solution to me, did you try that?

```
$correctDateBasedOnPeriod = function (FormEvent $event) {
    $period = $event->getForm()->getParent()->get('period')->getData();

    if (1 === $period) {
        $event->setData(new \DateTime('today'));
    } elseif (2 === $period) {
        $event->setData(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));
    }
};

$builder->get('start')->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, $correctDateBasedOnPeriod);
$builder->get('end')->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, $correctDateBasedOnPeriod);
```

This solution has the *minor drawback* that then "start" and "end" depend on "period" being submitted before them. Currently, this is the case - as long as you add "period" before adding the other fields - but there's no guarantee this will be the same in the future (due to potential optimizations).

However, should this ever change, you will most likely also have a new syntax to declare the dependencies between the fields and enable BC behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using events does allow me to set the form data correctly based on the period. However the browser doesn't display the correct dates based on the period in the start and end select box form fields. I can see this is because the viewdata for the select boxes (day,month year) is already set and cannot be changed. This isn't such a big deal given that the start and end can be hidden when the period is not "custom". Ideally I would like the select boxes to reflect the selected range allowing the user to tweak the range if required.

Comment: The effects of the SUBMIT event are shown in the field itself (not in the child fields though), so attaching listeners to the child fields should work?

Comment: Ah, you're speaking about date fields with select boxes. Could you open a ticket on the issue tracker? Maybe we can do something about this.

Comment: Yep I think this is an issue with date (and datetime) fields given that they have child forms which as you stated are not updated. Happy to create an issue for this to move the discussion off stackoverflow.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10070 I tried to summarise the issue the best I could.